# Where do I put these props for this component?

Tags: vue.js

**The answers say the same as what I've tried, so the answer is the component doesn't work.**

I'm trying to use this component
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mtcmedia/vue-tabs-accordion

It's working but I want to add props that it suggests

> Props The component accepts these props:
>
> mode: String. Default: 'accordion'    Can be set as 'tabs '
> responsive:   Object. Define mode for certain window widths This component is mobile first.
>
> {
> 640: {
> mode: 'tabs'
> },
> 1200: {
> mode: 'accordion'
> } }

however it doesn't say where to put them. I have tried various things in main.js such as

```
Vue.component('MtcTabsAccordion', props: [
    responsive:{
        640: {
            mode: 'tabs'
        },
        1200: {
            mode: 'accordion'
        }
    }
]);
```

I tried adding them as MtcTabsAccordionProps in the export default data, and adding `:responsive="MtcTabsAccordionProps"` in the component 's attributes but it just outputted in the HTML as `responsive="[Object]"`.

I've tried adding them to the export default props, but I can't imagine they should be there are the keys "responsive" and "mode" are too non-specific and would clash with others.

Where am I supposed to add the props?

Answer (score 3):

These are the props it accepts when using it:

```
<mtc-tabs-accordion:mode="mode" :responsive="responsive">
 ...
</mtc-tabs-accordion>
```

you can define mode and responsive in `data` or `setup` if you are using Vue3.

Comment: That's one of the things I listed as already tried. I now suspect the component doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with your template, to see how you use the Component. 
I understand the Components as a couple you need to use together

Comment: Just as you have. I had added the other requirement it needed which was MtcCollapsible. It worked but ignores the props. The component is broken; I've already moved on to use a different solution.

Comment: I would mark it as the correct answer because the code is sound, but that would mislead others who have this issue into thinking the component works.